# How can i receive payment in bitcoin without using any API or 3rd party

Tags: bitcoin

I have a website to sell products. Prices are in EURO. I want to take payment in my personal bitcoin address. So, i have to generate the product price with address in a QR code besides the regular payments system. And the customer can pay to scan the QR code. My question is - how can i show the QR code with product price and address at payment section ?

Comment: You can write the code yourself.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting? No one here will write this for you - this site is more for helping you with problems in code you're already attempting to write. If it was easy enough for someone to spend the time writing it for a SO answer there wouldn't be 3rd parties doing it.

Answer (score -1):

If you think you've got it and TRUST only yourself you can write it all yourself.
In order to do it you'd have to develop things such as wallet service for creating addresses + listening for any incoming deposits on your addresses, maybe storing your private keys should be necessity since you're dealing with some sensitive stuff u know... cryptos....

Otherwise you can trust 3rd party services such as [BitGo](https://www.bitgo.com/) or [APIs](https://www.blockchain.com/api) provided by `blockchain.com` (previously knowns as `blockchain.info`)

DISCLAIMER: I don't have any affiliation with `bitgo.com`, `blockchain.com` or any other such services